# Is my BIOS at risk using the BIOS browser?

Tags: internet, browser, bios

Several BIOS provide an internet suite (Hyperspace, ExpressGate etc). This internet suite may be used to get online with a browser, skype, and a few other things without having to boot all the way into the main OS.

Given our contemporary environment in which worms, and what-not snow-ball

- Is the BIOS at risk using a BIOS integrated browser?
- How are such applications be updated?

Comment: Hyperspace and ExpressGate are simply just Linux optimized for quick booting, which resides in a read only memory area. Security wise, it's like booting to a Live CD.

Comment: @LieRyan You should put that in as an answer. :)

Comment: Given the feature set of these browser the number of attack vectors could be counted on a single hand that's missing fingers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperspace and ExpressGate are simply just Linux optimized for quick booting, which resides in a read only memory area. Security wise, it's like booting to a Live CD.

Some of these quick booting Linux also provides features such as quick switching between the Quick boot OS and the primary OS, these are implemented by booting these OS under a hypervisor, which is typically used by virtualization technologies. Security wise it's like switching between virtual machines or switching between hypervisor and virtualized machine.

Note actual implementation varies, poorly implemented quick booting, virtualized OS may open security holes that wouldn't have existed in properly configured dual booting, virtualized OS.

Comment: Ergo it _may_ (significant probability) be safer?

Comment: @Everyone: theoretically, if implemented well, they may be safer. However, as I said, implementation varies, some of these systems provides read only or even write access to the Windows partition. Also, they may not be updated as often as they should be, and that means they may not have security fixes from the latest Linux/Firefox/whatever software they have installed.

Comment: Fair enough (+: